# SharePoint 2013 - 2010 Approval Workflow Status Canceled When Completed

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, 2013

I have built a 2 party approval workflow using the 2010 workflow engine in SharePoint 2013.  The workflow begins and ends with Impersonation steps to handle permissions and the declaration of the form as a record.  The workflow runs against a library which uses a customized InfoPath form.

The issue is this: everything seems to be running well and the majority of the workflows complete as they should, but the other day there was a form outstanding for several days waiting for approval.  After the two approvals were completed the workflow set the workflow status to approved and then sent out the final email to the initiator as it should, but at this point it canceled for some reason.  So it canceled at the very end of the approval process (step 2 of 3) and failed to run the 3rd step (the impersonation step to declare the form as a record).  Also, the final workflow status is "Canceled."

I've attempted to look in the logs, but they're a bit convoluted and overwhelming to me and didn't find anything helpful.  Any help would be very appreciated as this is something I need to resolve since it didn't surface until I rolled out the workflow to production.

Comment: You will be stuck with including more logging with your workflows. Check the workflow logs and check the ULS log at the time the error has occurred. Noone will be able to help you, because we don't know what your workflow did and where the error occurred. Probably a permission problem with the user not being allowed to declare the record, but that's a guess.

Comment: That's the purpose of the impersonation step.  It has worked perfectly in every other case and no changes have been made since deployment.  Do you have any tips for working with the logs?  Any keywords to look for when troubleshooting workflows or tools for making them easier to read?  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Also, there is no mention of error anywhere in the workflow history which leads me to believe the logs may not be as helpful as previously thought.

Comment: The ULS Logs in the 15 hive /Logs. You can read them best with ULS Log Viewer http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ULSViewer. You could filter for Category:Workflows but most probably won't find your problem like that. Figure out the exact time the problem must have occured and check that log.

Comment: I've gone through the logs and nothing stood out to me.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: We've been having some issues with memory maxing out on the application server, is it possible this could cause issues with the workflow if something was purged from memory?  This is pretty fundamental I know, but my background is in finance not IT.

Comment: Maxed out memory leads to all kind of problems. Purging not really, but if an action was supposed to happen exactly at the moment the memory was full - the action won't happen as it might not have been written to the queue. Give the app server enough RAM for sure!